# MySQL Long First Query Time

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb

I have a website that has two main queries to the database which are pretty slow the first time they are run, after a bit of testing it appears to be an issue with MySQL. If I run the query directly in Sequal Pro when I run a query the first time it can take up to 4 seconds to run but running the same query again takes ~60ms, the query time is about the same locally as on our server, which make me think its not a server issue.

Not totally sure that increasing the buffer pool size will help too much as the number of potential query combinations is probably around 800K.

The tables in the database are innodb, both queries access the same table that has 52K records, most of the information I need has been grouped together into a 'searchfield' field which is indexed.

Only fields used in queries or are primary/foreign keys are being indexed.

I have tried changing the inner joins to a select statement in the "where" of the main query but this doesn't make the query any faster.

The queries are

**Query 1**

```
SELECT 
  `item_attribute`.`attribute_id` AS `attribute_id`,
  `attribute_value_id` AS `attribute_value_id`,
  `collection_attribute`.`title` AS `ca_title`,
  `collection_attribute`.`type` AS `ca_type`,
  `collection_attribute`.`is_collapsible` AS `ca_is_collapsible`,
  `collection_attribute`.`orderindex` AS `ca_orderindex`,
  `collection_attribute`.`multi_select` AS `ca_multi_select`,
  `item_attribute`.`item_id` AS `item_id`,
  `product`.`id` AS `product_id` 
  FROM `item_attribute`
  INNER JOIN `item` ON item.id = item_attribute.item_id
  INNER JOIN `product` ON product.id = item.product_id
  INNER JOIN `collection_attribute` ON item_attribute.attribute_id = collection_attribute.attribute_id
  INNER JOIN `attribute_value` ON attribute_value.id = item_attribute.attribute_value_id 
  WHERE ((`product`.`searchfilter` LIKE '%c:35∆%') AND (`collection_attribute`.`collection_id`='35')) AND (`attribute_value`.`active`=1)
  GROUP BY `attribute_value_id`
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `item_attribute`.`attribute_id` AS `attribute_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(item_attribute.attribute_value_id SEPARATOR \"-\") AS `attribute_value`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_value.title SEPARATOR \" - \") AS `title`
  FROM `item_attribute`
  LEFT JOIN `item` ON item.id = item_attribute.item_id 
  LEFT JOIN `attribute` ON attribute.id = item_attribute.attribute_id 
  LEFT JOIN `attribute_value` ON attribute_value.id = attribute_value_id 
  WHERE (`item`.`product_id`='894') AND (`attribute`.`is_option`=1) 
  GROUP BY `attribute_id`, `item_id`
```

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `orderindex` int(2) DEFAULT '-1',
  `search` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `searchfilter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `description` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_ibfk_1` (`type_id`),
  KEY `searchfilter` (`searchfilter`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `attribute_value` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1882 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `collection_attribute` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `collection_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `orderindex` int(2) DEFAULT '-1',
  `search` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `searchfilter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_collapsible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `type` enum('icon','checkbox','checkboxIcon','image') DEFAULT NULL,
  `multi_select` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `collection_attribute_ibfk_1` (`collection_id`),
  KEY `collection_attribute_ibfk_2` (`attribute_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `collection_attribute_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`collection_id`) REFERENCES `collection` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `collection_attribute_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attribute` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=140 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

```
    CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pattern_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `tom_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `navision_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `orderindex` int(2) DEFAULT '-1',
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `searchfilter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `pattern_series` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pattern_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `item_ibfk_1` (`product_id`),
  KEY `searchfilter` (`searchfilter`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `pattern_id` (`pattern_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `item_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pattern_id`) REFERENCES `pattern_series` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50060 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `item_attribute` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `attribute_id` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `attribute_value_id` (`attribute_value_id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `item_attribute_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attribute` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `item_attribute_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_value_id`) REFERENCES `attribute_value` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `item_attribute_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=857111 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute_value` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `orderindex` int(2) DEFAULT '-1',
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `searchfilter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3471 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_option` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `searches` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_type` enum('dropdown','switch','fingersizes') DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_label` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `orderindex` int(2) DEFAULT '-1',
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `searchfilter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `option_requires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_depends` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `is_option` (`is_option`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the initial query time would be great

Thanks in advance :)

-- **EDIT** --

**EXPLAIN SELECT query 1**
[image: Explain Select]

**EXPLAIN SELECT query 2**
[image: Explain select]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you perform a query after starting the server, nothing is cache, so the query needs to fetch stuff from disk.  All subsequent queries that access the same parts of the same tables will be much faster because of caching.  This is "normal".

If you have the "Query cache" enable (it is probably enabled by default), then the second time you run *exactly* the same query, it will *instantly* find the result from the Query cache.  By "exactly" I mean that not so much as a blank space has changed.  Nearly all "production" servers are better off turning off the Query cache.

innodb_buffer_pool_size should be about 70% of available RAM.  Changing the value won't affect a SELECT against a cold cache, but might help/hurt subsequent runs.  This does not seem to be relevant in your case, since the second run was quite fast.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see how the optimizer decided to execute them.

`LIKE '%c:35∆%'` -- cannot use an index because of the leading wild card.

What is `item_ids`?

`item_attribute` is an EAV schema pattern.  It sucks.  Both the queries are ugly, and scalability hurts.  It may help *some* to get rid of the `id` and make a compound PRIMARY KEY from a suitable combination of the other fields.  The hope is to use the PRIMARY KEY which is clustered with the data instead of having to bounce from the secondary key.  [More discussion of EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Assuming this has low cardinality, the index will probably never be used:
KEY `is_option` (`is_option`)

Comment: thanks for the info. I'll have a go a changing the wildcard to another join and see if that helps any. and thanks for the info about EAV, will see if I can get it to work with Yii :)      Spoke to the tech support for our server, and he recommended changing the pool size to 40%, even though I have seen on another post on here that it can go to 70%, but this only seems to hold 3 of query 1. We have 1 GB of RAM, so the pool size is currently about 400MB.

Comment: Ouch.  1GB.  Even 400MB is dangerously high.  Swapping is _very_ bad for MySQL performance, worse than having a now buffer_pool.  Check the rest of my.cnf  -- several other things may need lowering.

Comment: umm but you said 'innodb_buffer_pool_size should be about 70% of available RAM' its only set to 40% and now your saying thats too high. Im a bit confused as to what this should be set to now, it was originally only 48MB

Comment: 70% of **available** RAM, not 70% of **Total** RAM.  When you have less than 4GB of RAM, a lot of it is taken up by the OS, mysql, and other things.

Comment: I settled on 70% as a simple, safe, thing to state.  That was after machines became 4GB and bigger.  (For 128GB, 70% could be raised to 80-85, but the benefit is in "diminishing returns".)  Then came "virtual" and "cloud", with their "tiny" RAM allocations.  That has messed up my 70% and I have to emphasize "available", and watch for 2G and 1G machines.  If you go with 700M out of 1G, you will probably be "swapping" -- That is _much_ worse than lowering the buffer pool.

Comment: ah right, that makes a lot of sense, thanks for clarifying :)